# Get wifi access apoint signal strength in Windows

Tags: windows, wifi

I want to get all the wifi ap signal strength just by scanning in Windows.

I know the command below.

```
netsh wlan show interface
```

But it only tells you the signal of the connected wifi ap.

What I want to achieve is to get all the other wifi ap signal strength. Is there any equivalent command in Windows that works like

```
wpa_cli scan_result
```

in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type :

**netsh wlan show all**

you get all the details

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! But I'm still wondering whether there is a way to get wifi ap signal in dBm, rather than a percentage.

Comment: This command uses Wlan APIs and you can deduce dbm from %, from MSDN =>

_wlanSignalQuality

A percentage value that represents the signal quality of the network. WLAN_SIGNAL_QUALITY is of type ULONG. This member contains a value between 0 and 100. A value of 0 implies an actual RSSI signal strength of -100 dbm. A value of 100 implies an actual RSSI signal strength of -50 dbm. You can calculate the RSSI signal strength value for wlanSignalQuality values between 1 and 99 using linear interpolation._